# ¿Como añado una linea a un log?

Tags: python, python-3.x, condiciones, logger

```
 if os.path.exists('login.txt'):
     print ("El fichero login.txt existe")
 else:
     print ("El fichero login.txt no existe o la ruta en la que se encuentra es diferente")
```

¿Cuando el bucle me sale por el else, como puedo añadir esa línea a un log?
¿Hay algún código de retorno en Python como en linux el $? ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No entiendo la relación (si la hay) entre las dos preguntas que pones al final.

Para enviar mensajes a un log puedes simplemente abri el fichero de log en modo *append* (`"a"`) y usar `fichero.write()`, o utilizar el paquete [`logging`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/logging.html) si tienes necesidades más avanzadas (advertencia, no es apto para principiantes).

Respecto al código de retorno, entiendo que te refieres a que si puedes enviar al shell un *exit status*, para que éste pueda usarlo como parte de un shell script. La respuesta es afirmativa. Puedes usar `sys.exit(codigo_de_salida)`. Las funciones `quit()` y `exit()` también sirven de la misma forma (pues por debajo invocan a `sys.exit()`)

Answer (score 0):

1. En un Notebook:

Puedes ejecutar comandos linux en Python añadiendo `!` delante de la linea

Ejemplo:

`!echo 'El fichero login.txt no existe o la ruta en la que se encuentra es diferente' >> log_file_path`

2. En un fichero Python (con extensión .py):

En este caso se puede usar la librería os (función `os.system("comando")`).

Ejemplo:

`import os
os.system("echo 'El fichero login.txt no existe o la ruta en la que se encuentra es diferente' >> log_file_path")`

En cuanto a la función de retorno, tal y como se ha comentado, puedes usar la función `quit()` o `sys.exit("Error msg")` si quieres mostrar algun error por consola

Comment: Muchisímas gracias. Gracias a esto podré manejarme mucho mejor en Python

Comment: para python 3.7 me parece que no funciona los !comando_linux porque me da error de sintaxis

Comment: Para dejar un error me refiero a usar `sys.exit("Mensaje de error")`, que para tu proceso y además te muestra el mensaje de error.

Comment: Tienes razón @antoniop, para que no te de error la ejecución de un comando en un archivo .py puedes usar la librería `os` (función `os.system("comando"))`.  Espero que esto te funcione.

Ejemplo:

`os.system("echo 'El fichero login.txt no existe o la ruta en la que se encuentra es diferente' >> log_file_path")`

Comment: Perfecto. Gracias por la contestación. Ahora puedo manejarme muchísimo mejor en Python